# product.ImageUrl is missing, how do I create a correct default value?

Tags: missing-data

The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> product.ImageUrl  [in template "77759" at line 1064, column 57]

---

### Tip: It's the step after the last dot that caused this error, not those before it.

### Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault,
or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis:
(myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

```
- Failed at: ${product.ImageUrl}  [in template "77759" in macro "productTable2" at line 1064, column 55]  -> deze
- Reached through: @productTable2  [in template "92107" at line 35, column 5]
~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "77759" in macro "layout" at line 214, column 61]
~ Reached through: @layout  [in template "92107" at line 12, column 1]
```

I want to direct a fallback image link when the url is missing. Let's call the  fallback image url:

The code at line 1064 is:

<#if showThumb == true>

I tried:
<#if showThumb == true>

of course it did not work.